# Unity crashes when creating .exe

Tags: unity-game-engine, ram

When I build the game and try to execute it I get this error:

```
Test.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module Test.exe at 0033:93f8d26a.

Error occurred at 2016-11-22_091146.

83% memory in use.
3980 MB physical memory [677 MB free].
6857 MB paging file [1326 MB free].
134217728 MB user address space [134217031 MB free].
Read from location 00000890 caused an access violation.
```

I guess I need more RAM (I am using a 83%). What should I do to be able to play the game? 
Is it a problem of not having enough RAM or I can fix doing something in unity?

Comment: Buy more ram...

Comment: There is plenty of topics on the internet. Just type `unity caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)`. There may be more than one reason why this crashes. You have to try everything.